# max-width with responsive embedded iframe in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am using `embed-responsive-16by9` to vary the size of some embedded videos in a column based bootstrap layout:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 concept-video">
                <iframe src="" width="476" height="268" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 concept-video">
                <iframe src="" width="476" height="268" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the screen is smaller the columns stack instead of being next to each other (as they should), and at this point the videos become wider than I need them to be, so I have used css to set a maximum width for the div:

```
.concept-video {
    max-width: 476px;
}
```

This is working to set a maximum width, but the heights of the videos are still the same height as they were without the maximum width, so they have black space above and below in the iframe. How do I make the height of the video be correct relative to the width?

I have tried setting the `max-height` to the correct height for the `max-width`, but this had no effect:

```
.concept-video {
    max-width: 476px;
    max-height: 268px; !important
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try removing your custom css like `concept-video` then try the code below.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"></iframe>
 </div>
</div
```

And if you wanted to see the divs next to each other when in mobile then
change your div class to `<div class="col-xs-6">`

Comment: That's just going back to the standard behaviour of embed-responsive. I am wanting to set a maximum width on the videos without the height behaving strangely (column behaviour is fine)

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of what you are actually looking for?